# Xcode 6 - What is the reason behind extra space between keyboard rows?

Tags: iphone, ios8, keyboard, size, xcode6

what is the reason behind extra space between keyboard rows? when I create a new project, keyboard appears normal as required. See the images

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer for my question.
For this problem, I had to compatible my old Xcode project for iPhone 6 and 6+.
In short, you need to apply app Launch Image for iOS8 or Later.
Click on Project>AppLaunch Image>Inspector menu>Tick on iOS8 and Later option and Drag N drop Images in image asset.[image] [image]